# Android: listview is not displying

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am creating an list view inside fragment but it is not displaying i have stuck.I am passing data from mainActivity.java to OrderDetailsAdapter.java but getview() function is not getting called and getcount returning nonzero
Here is my code

OrderDetailsAdapter.java

```
public class OrderDetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OrderDetails> {
    Context context;
    int resource;
    private List<OrderDetails> orderList = new ArrayList<OrderDetails>();

    public OrderDetailsAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(OrderDetails object) {
        orderList.add(object);
        Log.v("getcount", "addItems " + getCount());
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int size  = orderList.size();
        Log.v("getcount","getcount "+ size);
        return orderList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public OrderDetails getItem(int index) {
        return orderList.get(index);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.v("getcount","I am getting called");
        View row = convertView;
        OrderDetailsHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            row = layoutInflater.inflate(resource,parent,false);

            holder = new OrderDetailsHolder();
            holder.patientName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.order_list_view_patient_name);
            holder.price = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.order_list_view_price);
            holder.medicineList = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.order_list_view_medicine_list);
            holder.expirationTime = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.order_list_view_expiration_time);
            holder.expirationText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.order_list_view_order_expire_text);
            holder.cancelOrder = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.order_list_view_cancel_order);
            holder.openOrder = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.order_list_view_open_order);

        //Assigning custom fonts
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/gothic.ttf");
            holder.patientName.setTypeface(typeface);
            holder.price.setTypeface(typeface);
            holder.expirationTime.setTypeface(typeface);
            holder.medicineList.setTypeface(typeface);
            holder.expirationText.setTypeface(typeface);
            holder.cancelOrder.setTypeface(typeface);
            holder.openOrder.setTypeface(typeface);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (OrderDetailsHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        final OrderDetails details = getItem(position);
        Log.v("AAAA",details.toString());
       // OrderDetails orderDetails1 = orderList[position];
        holder.patientName.setText(details.getPatientName());
        holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(details.getPrice()) +" /-");
        holder.medicineList.setText(Arrays.toString(details.getMedicineList()));
        holder.expirationTime.setText(String.valueOf(details.expirationTime)+" mins");
        return row;
     }

    static class OrderDetailsHolder {
        TextView patientName;
        TextView price;
        TextView medicineList;
        TextView expirationTime;
        TextView expirationText;
        TextView openOrder;
        TextView cancelOrder;
    }}
```

OrderDetails.java

```
public class OrderDetails {
    public String patientName;
    public float price;
    public String medicineList[];
    public int expirationTime;

    public OrderDetails()
    {
        super();
    }

    public OrderDetails(String patientName,float price,String[] medicineList,int expirationTime)
    {
        this.patientName = patientName;
        this.price = price;
        this.medicineList = medicineList;
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
    }

    public String getPatientName(){
        return patientName;
    }

    public float getPrice() {   return  price;  }

    public String[] getMedicineList() { return medicineList;    }

    public int getExpirationTime() { return  expirationTime; }}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon_home);
    TextView userAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawerHeaderTextView2);
    userAddress.setText("52N 12, Pratap Nagar");
    replaceFragment(R.layout.fragment_order_list, null);


    //Set adapter for Order List
    String medicineList[] = {"Paracetamol","Crocin","Azithomycin","Strepsils"};
    orderDetails = new OrderDetails("Ravi Gupta",220,medicineList,20);
    OrderDetailsAdapter orderDetailsAdapter = new OrderDetailsAdapter(this,R.layout.order_list_view_items);

    orderDetailsAdapter.add(orderDetails);
    orderDetailsAdapter.add(orderDetails);
    orderDetailsAdapter.add(orderDetails);
    orderDetailsAdapter.add(orderDetails);  }
```

HELP PLZ

Comment: Did you set the adapter on your listview?

Comment: in onCreate of MainActivity listView.setAdapter(your Adapter);

Comment: Where is your list you have not passed the list to the adapters. You have just initialized it inside your adapter. That is why your list is not showing.

Comment: where is your fragment class ?

Comment: You should have used `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)` this constructor to create an object of Adapter class and pass your list detail as a third parameter in your code

Comment: did you log in your add function is shown when you call to add some object to the data of adapter? I think problem is in add function

Comment: @ThomasR. how to set adapter to list view?

Comment: In your fragment layout there should be your listview. In the onViewCreated() method you should get the listview by using findViewById() method. After that set your created adapter on the listview.

Comment: that means i have to create instance of orderlistadapter in my fragment?

Comment: @BBdev in fragment class how i will get the list details?

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper no it doesnt work

Comment: int size  = orderList.size();  return orderList.size(); that's funny stuff, almmost coding comedy :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this `public OrderDetailsAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<OrderDetails> orderList) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.orderList = orderList;
    }` and this `OrderDetailsAdapter orderDetailsAdapter = new OrderDetailsAdapter(this,R.layout.order_list_view_items,orderList);`

Comment: where i have to define this line OrderDetailsAdapter orderDetailsAdapter = new OrderDetailsAdapter(this,R.layout.order_list_view_items,orderList);

Comment: in your mainactivity when you initialize your adapter

Comment: one last doubt what is orderList in Main Activity

Comment: orderList must be an array of items (names or any thing you want to display in your listview)